# Add hyperlinked text to right of field on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, hyperlink

I'd like to build a field similar to the standard *Owner* field, which includes a 
*[Change]* link immediately to the right of the field value.

**However**, the additional requirement I have is that the link open in a new window.

Things I've tried:

**1.**`<apex:outputlink>`

Allows opening in new window, but it acts as a separate pageblock item, so I can't put it immediately to the right of a field value

**2.**`<apex:outputText label="fieldLabel" value="{!Object.fieldValue} [{!LINKTO(...)}]"/>`

This method will display the LINKTO value as part of the field value, which is good. However, LINKTO does not allow me to specify opening a new window.

**3.**`<apex:outputText label="fieldLabel" value="{!Object.fieldValue} [{!HYPERLINK(...)}]"/>`

HYPERLINK function does allow me to specific opening a new window, but when trying to use in a visualforce value returns the error `problem: Function HYPERLINK may not be used in this type of formula`

---

Now I'm trying to mess with straight HTML (ie the `<a>` tag), but I'm not sure how to get it to display immediately to the right of the field value.

Your help as always is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found a working answer here: [Position elements side by side within a single pageBlockSection column](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44281/position-elements-side-by-side-within-a-single-pageblocksection-column)

The key is to use an `<apex:panelGrid>` within a `<apex:pageBlockSectionitem>`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use anchor tag to achieve this functionality

```
<apex:outputText label="fieldLabel" value="{!Object.fieldValue}"/>
<a href="javascript:window.open('url')">
 Change
</a>
```

And with the use of `outputLink`:

```
<apex:outputLink onclick="javascript:window.open('url')">
   Change
 </apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: Hah if it's really as simple as putting the anchor tag next to the outputtext tag, I will feel quite silly. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, true, please accept and close this question

Comment: Santanu, this doesn't solve my issue. The resulting link isn't immediately to the right of the field, like the Ownership field. Rather, it occupies the second column similar to a `<apex:outputLink>'. My use case is to have a 'Description' link next to the field label/value, that can be clicked on for a detailed field description.

Comment: But you didn't specified this in your question earlier,  anyway good to hear that it solved by panel grid